# Cannot extend from a typeof variable

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a library using commonJS modules and I'd like to define classes in their own modules in a "lib" directory and then have a "main" module that imports and exports classes from the modules in the "lib" directory. I want the consumer of the library to be able to extend the exported classes, but the typescript compiler doesn't seem to support this. The code below is a simplified repro using internal modules. The compiler emits an error for class `BC`. Is there a workaround?

```
module A {
    export class C {
    }
}

module B {
    export var C = A.C;
}

// this compiles
class AC extends A.C { }

// and this compiles
var bc = new B.C();

// this does not compile.
// compiler error: TS2305 Module 'B' has no exported member 'C'
class BC extends B.C {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bring `A.C` into the *type declaration space* (`import` keyword) and not the *variable declaration space* (`var` keyword).

```
module A {
    export class C {
    }
}

module B {
    export import C = A.C;
}

// this compiles
class AC extends A.C { }

// and this compiles
var bc = new B.C();

// NO ERROR
class BC extends B.C {
}
```