# typescript import alias or variable declaration with commonjs

Tags: typescript

The follow constructs generate the same js and type hints. Is there any difference between the two, and when should one be used over the other?

Import alias:

```
import mod = require('./mod');
import Foo = mod.Foo;
var foo = new Foo();
```

Variable alias:

```
import mod = require('./mod');
var Foo = mod.Foo;
var foo = new Foo();
```

Output from both w/commonjs:

```
var mod = require('./mod');
var Foo = mod.Foo;
var foo = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the two, and when should one be used over the other?

Yes. `import` also brings it into the *type* declaration space. This is only significant for TypeChecking and not significant in the generated JS.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26983363/390330 for an example.